# testing rails app with cucumber and capybara won't recognize current_path.should == new_session_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to make a simple assertion on expected path.

in my step definition file, according to the capybara docs:

```
Then /^I should be on the login page/ do
  current_path.should == new_session_path
end
```

this returns

```
undefined method `new_session_path' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x0000010340b4c0> (NoMethodError)
```

It looks as though it's not loading the route helpers..

Comment: could you add your features/support/paths.rb and your config/routes.rb files to give us a little pinch where the error might come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a brain-fart issue.  Really sorry about that. A detail that eluded me for a long time was that I was running into rails' engine isolation issue. Specifically I was testing refinerycms and running into the problem described here: https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/issues/1259

so to fix it was dead simple:

```
current_path.should == refinery.admin_root_path
```